# Hot to get basic Force.com Site usage statistics?

Tags: force.com-sites

My client is looking for basic Force.com Site usage statistics. We could install [this AppExchange app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001SUEwEAO), but I wanted to see if there are any less-intrusive options before going this route.

We need to know for the last 90 days, how many unique visitors visited the site.

Is this possible without this AppExchange app?

Comment: Presumably, you could query all the data yourself; this is just some simple dashboards. That said, it's a free app, so why not?

Comment: Yeh, that was the first thing I thought of, but looking at the schema explorer in eclipse, I couldn't figure out which objects to query.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, Salesforce does not have any accessible objects one can query or report on, unless you install [the AppExchange app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000001SUEwEAO). Even then, the all that appears to be available to report is bandwidth and page views, neither all that useful for determining how many people access your Site.

What we decided to do is install Google Analytics and use that data going forward.